# Is changing the user-agent and sending Authorization to download with v3 extension still possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

To download firmware directly from the Samsung server I need to send the User-Agent and Authorization, I tried to do this with javascript, but on the front-end CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) prevents it.

So I thought about using a Google Chrome extension to manipulate the download headers, but I'm not succeeding and Google now only accepts manifest_version: 3 and the documentation shows an example that only accepts manifest_version: 2.

Does anyone know if it's still possible?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "chrome.downloads",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "downloads",
    "downloads.open",
    "downloads.shelf",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
console.log("background.js");

function checkObject (details)
{
 console.log("onBeforeSendHeaders")
 console.log(details)

}

function onMessage(details, sender, callback)
{
    console.log("details")
    console.log(sender)


    chrome.downloads.download({
        filename: "Example.html",
        url: "https://test"
    })
}

/*chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        console.log("onBeforeSendHeaders");
        for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
            if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
                details.requestHeaders.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["requestHeaders"]
);*/

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log("onBeforeSendHeaders");
    console.log(details);
},{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},['requestHeaders']);



chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(checkObject,
    {
        urls: ["<all_urls>"]
    },["responseHeaders"]);

//chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(checkObject);


chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(delta) {
    console.log("delta");
    console.log(delta);
    /*chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(false);
    if (delta.state.current == 'in_progress'){
        State=true;
    }
    else if (delta.state.current == 'complete'){
        State=false;
        chrome.storage.local.clear;
        chrome.storage.local.set({'lastDownloaded' : delta});
        chrome.downloads.show(delta.id);
    }
    chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(true);*/
});


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessage);

/*chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(arg, sender, sendResponse) {
    onMessage();
    chrome.downloads.download({
        filename: "Example.html",
        url: "https://test"
    });
});*/
```

chrome.webRequest doesn't work, the event simply doesn't fire and does anyone know if it would be possible to manipulate the direct header chrome.downloads.download

I was hoping to change the download request header to download the file, I can do this in python and in js on the front-end I can't because of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) and I need the extension to manipulate the header without CORS restrictions

Comment: See examples of using declarativeNetRequest instead of webRequest.

Comment: Hello friend, from what I understand it is not possible to manipulate the download header using declarativeNetRequest

Comment: Sounds like you misunderstood. It should be possible, otherwise it would be a bug.